# optimize java code and how to make it look good

Tags: java, optimization

I have a piece of code, it's always used but it looked very redundant , and what can I do for sidestepping redundancy.

```
        if(CommonUtil.isNull(second.getProvince())) {
            second.setProvince(first.getProvince());
        }

        if(CommonUtil.isNull(second.getCity())) {
            second.setCity(first.getCity());
        }

        if(CommonUtil.isNull(second.getDistrict())) {
            second.setDistrict(first.getDistrict());
        }

        if(CommonUtil.isNull(second.getAddress())) {
            second.setAddress(first.getAddress());
        }

        ........
```

Comment: You could use reflection or lambdas in a loop.

Comment: You could use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) and if it doesn't provide ignoring already set fields out of the box you can provide your own converter/mapper ([How can I tell Dozer to bypass mapping null or empty string values per field using the programming api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256952/how-can-i-tell-dozer-to-bypass-mapping-null-or-empty-string-values-per-field-usi)).

Comment: how can I use lambdas, about this case?

Comment: A bit more about the context would be nice. For example how about applying the properties of `first` first, and then overwrite them with the other source? It may not be possible in your case but if it is, you wouldn't have to check for nulls at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this method in your data classes and do null control of all fields with one line of code. My code advice is like below:

```
public boolean copyIfNull(Object o)
{

        Class<?> clazz = this.getClass();
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        for(Field field : fields)
        {
        try {
            Object fieldValue = field.get(this);
            if (fieldValue == null)
            {
                field.set(this, field.get(o));
                return false;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Field value could not be obtained");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        }


    return true;

}
```

And you will call this method in main like that:

```
second.copyIfNull(first)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your objects look like beans from afar, you might have a look at java.beans.Introspector and BeanInfo.

Roughly along the lines of:

```
BeanInfo bi = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyObjectClass.class);
for(PropertyDescriptor p : bi.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    // perform null-check
    // invoke read on source object via read method delivered by p.getReadMethod()
    // write to target via method delivered by p.getWriteMethod()
}
```